# Shiny: update selectizeInput choices based on selected

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to update the `choices` of a `selectizeInput` based on the current `selected` choices. Here is my attempt (causes loop):

```
library(shiny)
run_ui <- function() {

  ui <- selectizeInput('words', 'Search words:', choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = NULL)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # change 'Search words' ----
    observeEvent(input$words, {

      # handle no words (reset everything)
      if (is.null(input$words)) {
        cowords <- letters

      } else {
        # update cowords (choices for selectizeInput)
        cowords <- unique(c(input$words, sample(letters, 5)))
      }

      # update UI
      print('updating')
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'words', choices = cowords, selected = input$words, server = TRUE)

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  }
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
}

run_ui()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stick to `server = TRUE`, it's maybe not a trivial problem.

One possible work-around could be to `debounce` the input that you are observing, and then check and only update in case there is a change. This could look as follows - I added some `print` statements such that you can better follow what's happening.

```
library(shiny)

run_ui <- function() {

  ui <- selectizeInput('words', 'Search words:', choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = NULL)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    val <- "a"
    pasteCollPlus <- function(...) {
      paste(..., collapse = "+")
    }

    wordSelect <- debounce(reactive({input$words}), millis = 50)

    # change 'Search words' ----
    observeEvent(wordSelect(), {

      # handle no words (reset everything)
      if (is.null(input$words)) {
        cowords <- letters
      } else {
        # update cowords (choices for selectizeInput)
        cowords <- unique(c(input$words, sample(letters, 5)))
      }

      if (isTRUE(pasteCollPlus(val) == pasteCollPlus(input$words))) {
        print(paste("No update - val is", pasteCollPlus(val)))
      } else {
        # update UI
        print(paste("updating selection to", pasteCollPlus(input$words)))
        print(paste("val is", pasteCollPlus(val)))
        val <<- input$words
        updateSelectizeInput(session, 'words', choices = cowords, selected = input$words, server = TRUE)
      }

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  }
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
}

run_ui()
```

---

**Edit**

Another work-around would be to **handle the bouncing pattern** explicitly, in order to block it. This is maybe even less elegant, but could be more robust for more involved / complex cases (apps). An example for this follows:

```
library(shiny)
run_ui <- function() {

  ui <- selectizeInput('words', 'Search words:', choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = NULL)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    val <- "a"
    newVal <- NULL
    pasteCollPlus <- function(...) {
      paste(..., collapse = "+")
    }

    # change 'Search words' ----
    observeEvent(input$words, {

      # handle no words (reset everything)
      if (is.null(input$words)) {
        cowords <- letters
      } else {
        # update cowords (choices for selectizeInput)
        cowords <- unique(c(input$words, sample(letters, 5)))
      }

      if (isTRUE(pasteCollPlus(val) == pasteCollPlus(input$words))) {
        print(paste("No update - val is", pasteCollPlus(val)))
        val <<- newVal
      } else {
        # update UI
        print(paste("updating selection to", pasteCollPlus(input$words)))
        print(paste("val is", pasteCollPlus(val)))
        print(paste("newVal is", pasteCollPlus(newVal)))

        val <<- NULL
        newVal <<- input$words

        updateSelectizeInput(session, 'words', choices = cowords, selected = input$words, server = TRUE)
      }

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  }
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
}

run_ui()
```

Comment: Thanks Roland. This works but seems a bit fragile - the actual app varies in how long the update calculation takes. I had to make `millis = 3000` for `debounce` and I'm guessing it would have to be higher if running on a less powerful computer?

Comment: The long debounce also slows down fast updates unnecessarily.

Comment: yes, I agree, it's well possible that it's not ideal for your actual production setup. I edited the answer to give you an alternative. hope that helps

Comment: Thanks Roland, I've managed to get the edited solutions working although I don't follow the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Do you **need** to use server-side selectize? If not, then your code would work fine as-is by simply removing that part.

```
library(shiny)
run_ui <- function() {

  ui <- selectizeInput('words', 'Search words:', choices = NULL, selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE, options = NULL)

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # change 'Search words' ----
    observeEvent(input$words, {

      # handle no words (reset everything)
      if (is.null(input$words)) {
        cowords <- letters

      } else {
        # update cowords (choices for selectizeInput)
        cowords <- unique(c(input$words, sample(letters, 5)))
      }

      # update UI
      print('updating')
      updateSelectizeInput(session, 'words', choices = cowords, selected = input$words)

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  }
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
}

run_ui()
```

Comment: Yes - in the real app, `cowords` is very large.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution simply updates the entire object through renderUI and re-draws it, rather than passing back an update via updateSelectizeInput().  This does allow choices to be fully managed on the server-side.  A downside is that it fires with each change event, which means that the `multiple=TRUE` is moot since the object redraws with each change.  If multiples are critical, I think the `updateSelectizeInput()` approach or any other solution that updates `onChange`, would run into the same issue.  To allow multiple choices, the event would need to move to `onBlur` or a mouseout event.  Otherwise, the event trigger doesn't know if a user intends to select only one choice and fire; or wait for the user to make multiple choices before firing.  However, blur or mouseout might make it behave strangely from the user's perspective.  A button forcing the update action would resolve this.  Keeping the update based on the first select, solution as follows:

```
library(shiny)
run_ui <- function() {

  ui <- uiOutput(outputId="select_words")      
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # change 'Search words' ----
    output$select_words <- renderUI({    
      cowords <- letters
      if (!is.null(input$words)) cowords <- unique(c(input$words, sample(letters, 5)))
      print(paste("Updating words: ",paste0(cowords,collapse=",")))

      return (tagList(selectizeInput('words', 'Search words:', choices = cowords, selected = input$words, multiple = TRUE, options = NULL)))
    })
  }
  runGadget(shinyApp(ui, server), viewer = browserViewer())
}

run_ui()
```

Comment: Thanks Soren. Trying to implement this did not scale as well as `updateSelectizeInput`. To make it more comparable, `cowords <- sample(letters, 348000, replace=TRUE)`

Comment: This implies a drop-down list of 348,000 items -- there's a matter of data from server to client whether using updateSelectizeInput() or any other solution?  The scaling is sending back a lot of data more than the technique to do it, I think.  Equally, will your drop down list have 300,000+ items exposed to users; it seems a cumbersome list to use.  If you're sampling a sub-set from this huge list, the subsetting server side should be quite speedy.

Comment: Also, keeping in the example of using `letters` to note that HTML drop-down menus will only display unique items.  So passing 348,000 redundant items to the drop-down menu will then only result in a list of 26 unique letters.  I realize it's just an example, but if your application list has redundant items, this issue will also present itself there, too.

Comment: Yes the 348,000 items are all unique. I'm not sure that the `selectizeInput` shows all the items, but having them all as `choices` makes all of them searchable. I tried implementing your solution because it's less convoluted than RolandASc's answer (which renders without issue) but the search input wasn't rendering within minutes. I just gave the letters example to reproduce the lag I experienced.